# It is possible to set the priority of overloaded operator+ in regard to used classes?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have two classes:

```
class_1 a,b;
class_2 u,v;
```

where I have `operator+` defined between all class combinations. All additions output a `class_1` for all class combinations on both sides of + operator.

Then I have an expression:

```
a = u + v + b;
```

Is it possible to execute `operator+` between `class_1` and `class_2` always with higher priority then between `class_2` and `class_2`? If its not, is there some kind of internal rule to make for example always "more left" operator first (even with /Ox)?

Comment: Addition associates to the left – `x + y + z` is always `(x + y) + z`. It would be really annoying if you had to look up the associativity for every addition.

Comment: Its not a question of what you have on result. operator+ should have associativity be default otherwise its problably not wise to use + in that case. Its just question of performance. For my example, addition of classes class_1 with class_2 is double time faster than class_2 with class_2. But the results will be same, so anyone who use that will not be confused by precedense. Its used in one kind of physical simulation so performance is quite an issue.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, it is not possible to change the precedence, grouping, or number of operands of operators. But you can use parenthesis if you wish so.